# when i am jmater executing on the time" time stamp different "is showing i have time stamp code also

Tags: node.js, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

when i am j meter  executing on the on  time" time stamp different "is showing i have time stamp code also i am give but i have got the is error
Request Rejected >> getAccountFromDB . Timestamp Mismatch with Server    'TO CLIENT': '{"ERRORCODE":"520","ERRORMSG":"ERR_INVALID_REQ","MSG":"R

```
Request Rejected >> getAccountFromDB . Timestamp Mismatch with Server
   'TO CLIENT': '{"ERRORCODE":"520","ERRORMSG":"ERR_INVALID_REQ","MSG":"Request Rejected >> getAccountDetails . Server to Client Time Diff is : 43307(secs)","GUID":""}'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have a hard-coded ([recorded](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html)?) timestamp somewhere in your request which is not accepted by the server because the time is not current.

You need to find this parameter and replace it with [__time()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time) function, by default it returns current timestamp in milliseconds since beginning of [Unix epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), if your parameter format is different you can amend the output via [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) patterns.

More information on JMeter Functions concept: [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-functions)